# UPnP browser/player for OS X

Tags: gratis, osx, video, dlna

I am looking for software that works on OS X, can browse an UPnP/DLNA server and can play video content in various formats from it.

VLC is supposed to be able to do this but the current version is buggy and it's not possible to enable the UPnP module (there are many complaints about it online).